# how to generate top grading snapshot chart?

Tags: highcharts, stacked-area-chart

I want to generate a topgrading snapshot chart using any jquery library like shown below.  But so far, I only succeeded in generating the top part of the chart ("Salary" in the example image). [Here is my first attempt using Highcharts](https://jsfiddle.net/aLnc2nbv) (code below),

[image]

I do not know how to include the part below, which shows various numerical ratings in a tile chart style ("Boss rating", "Reason" etc. in the example image).

The lower part could be included using a [heatmap](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap) but I do not know how to combine it with the plot above.

**How is it possible to include the tiles with the labels below the stacked chart plot?** If it's not possible using Highcharts, I can also do with another jQuery library.

Below is example code of what I have so far:

---

HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'area',
        spacingBottom: 20
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Fruit consumption *'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: '* Jane\'s banana consumption is unknown',
        floating: true,
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        y: 15
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'horizontal',
        align: 'bottom',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        x: 150,
        y: 100,
        floating: false,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme &&    
                             Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) ||
                         '#FFFFFF'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Oranges', 'Bananas', 
                    'Grapes', 'Plums', 'Strawberries', 'Raspberries']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Y-Axis'
        },
        labels: {
          formatter: function () {
                return this.value;
          }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
          return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
            this.x + ': ' + this.y;
          }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        area: {
          fillOpacity: 0.5
        }
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
          name: 'John',
          data: [4,5]
        }, {
          name: 'Jane',
          data: [2,2],  
        }, {
          name: 'Jane',
          data: [1,1],          
        }, {
          name: 'Jane',
          data: [null,null,4,6],      
        }, {
          name: 'Jane',
          data: [null,null,2,2],   
        }, {
          name: 'Jane',
          data: [null,null,1,1],    
    }]
  });
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aLnc2nbv/ I tried this but I cant get all labels on right side etc...

Comment: @akraf : my expectation is not to develop entire solution, I am expecting only which allow to combine area and column chart together, its enough for me.

Comment: I edited your question to include the code you posted and your question. Please review and correct if nessecary. I also included the question which you posted in the comments in the question. Please review if I understood you correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this **live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/us14vpa7/

I created a separate y axis for hetmap series and set primary axis' height to `'70%'` so that ticks and labels for values lower then 0 are not visible. `linkedTo` causes that secondary axis has the same extremes as the primary one (heatmap series are not superposed on area series).

```
  yAxis: [{
    // primary
    min: -3,
    height: '70%',
    min: 0
  }, { // heatmap series axis
    visible: false,
    linkedTo: 0,
  }],
```

Every area series has a corresponding heatmap series. `colsize` property in heatmap is a distance between the lowest and the highest x value in corresponding area series:

```
// first block
{ // area series
  type: 'area',
  data: [
    [0, 0],
    [0, 4],
    [1.5, 7],
    [1.5, 0]
  ],
  marker: {
    enabled: true
  }
}, { // corresponding heatmap series
  type: 'heatmap',
  data: [
    [0.75, -0.5, 0],
    [0.75, -1.5, 0]
  ],
  colsize: 1.5
}
```

---

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.heatmap.colsize
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.linkedTo